# Reactions involving carboxylic acids

Tags: organic-chemistry, esters

The following question was given in FIITJEE study material:

> [image]

I guess **(i)** step is de-esterification, which gives the compound of option **(A)**.

In next step, I wouldn't expect it to decarboxylate, instead I guess it'll dehydrate. So, according to me, final product is:

[image]

which I can't see in the options. Then, what should be the final product?

---

> The correct answer given was: **(C)**

Comment: The conditions for the first step specify base but not water present, so you are not going to get hydrolysis which means the product is not A . What might a sufficiently strong base do to the starting material?

Comment: @Waylander: Ok, so this is Claisen condensation. And, then [this is the product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc7y0.png), which converts into acid on hydrolysis and finally decarboxylate on ∆. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Correct. Depending on how strong the acid is, how long you heat it and to what temperature.

Comment: The answer is B. You use NaOEt as the base to avoid trans-esterification.

Comment: @joehua: I agree with your expl. But, I think we get (B) in the first step itself, what about the second one?

Comment: Now, I see that when acid is added, the solution is also heated. So, clearly, this is hydrolysis then decarboxylation. The answer should be C.